# Clean-up needed: [support] & [customer-support]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, clean-up

I draw your attention to the [support](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) tag.

No tag wiki or usage guidance, of course.

The questions tagged thus appear to be, by and large, questions asking *for* support, rather than questions asking *about* support. (In other words, the tag is being used to describe the *kind* of question, rather than the *topic* of the question, which is a classic sign of a meta tag.)

The tag [customer-support](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customer-support) is essentially the same. I'd suggest they be synonyms if they weren't so useless for categorizing questions.

I can't see that either tag is useful. Certainly each *needs* other tags to fully describe the content of the question. (More meta tag smell.)

These questions need cleaning up. Does anyone have a compelling reason to keep either tag?

(As always, if you're helping out with this clean-up project, don't *just* fix the tag; fix all of the problems with the post. And only do a couple at a time, so as not to flood the front page with edits.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've cleaned up both the meta tags